Where is the orthogonality center of the AKLT ground state matrix product state?
It is a known fact that the ground state of the 1D Affleck-Kennedy-Lieb-Tasaki model (AKLT) can be represented as a matrix product state (MPS) of the following form:
$$
\left|{\psi}\right\rangle = \sum_{\sigma_1\cdots \sigma_N}{\rm Tr}\left(A^{\sigma_1} \cdots A^{\sigma_N}\right) \left|{\sigma}\right\rangle
$$
Where the tensors $A^\sigma$ are:
$$
\begin{array}{lcr}
A^{+1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt{2/3}\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & A^{0}=\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{1/3} & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{1/3}
\end{pmatrix} & A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
-\sqrt{2/3} & 0
\end{pmatrix}\end{array}
$$
It is a result of treating each site as composed of two spin-1/2 virtual particles, where each pair of spins of different sites are anti-symmetric, and the whole virtual state is projected onto the whole spin-1 space.
Assuming these exact tensors, where is the orthogonality center of the MPS?

First, if I am correct, the matrix elements $\sqrt{3/2}$ should be instead $\sqrt{2/3}$.
Then you can check that both left and right normalization conditions are satisfied on every site, i.e., $\sum_{\sigma} {A^{\sigma}}^{\dagger} A^{\sigma} = \sum_{\sigma} A^{\sigma} {A^{\sigma}}^{\dagger} = \mathbb{I}$. This means that all the sites are the orthognality center of this translationally invariant MPS.

Oh, you're right, its indeed 2/3. Probably a typo, so I fixed it. Anyways, what does it mean that the orthogonality center is all of the sites? For example, assuming I want to contract the MPS around a local operator (e.g. $S_z$ on site $i$), does that mean I don't have to move the orthogonality center to the site?

No, you don't have to. The picture in your mind about the orthogonality center might be the case for a finite chain with open boundary condition, left and right of which in left- and right-canonical form, respectively. For periodic boundary condition, it is not necessarily possible. But here the state is also translationally invariant, which you can think about as an infinite-MPS that ends with open boundary condition and put the site you want in the cneter of the chain. To contract with a local opeartor it is completely fine.

OK, I think I get it now. So, when thinking of a finite MPS as a part of an infinite one (or, alternatively, with PBC), then there's no need to orthogonalize. But for OBC I would need to move the ortho-center to the site, right? If so, my original question still stands: where do I move the ortho-center from? How is it done?
I do see that this is a bit of a different question than before, so I may open a new question regarding that, or change this one to better reflect my understanding.

@YoavZack It is not really that there is no need to orthogaonalize with PBC, but that in this case the state is already in canonical form with all the sites being the orthogonality center, as we can compute. In the general case of OBC, if there is no orthogonality center, we shold always start from one end of the chain and do SVD (or QR) successively for each site. You can refer to any of the review papers / textbooks for MPS, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477 (section 4.1.3).

This is only correct for infinite chains.
